# News Plugin Insert Page

Tags: tx-news

I updated the plugin, updated the database and flushed all cashes. Unfortunately plugin is no longer available in the backend.

[image]

> INVALID VALUE ("news_pi1")" I also checked the include option in the template but there also "News" is selected. Can someone help me how to fix this? Regards :)

I reinstalled  the plugin, flushed cashes, updated database scheme.

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question needs improvement. Your title should be a clear, specific question.

Answer (score 0):

I did the following:

```
update tt_content set ctype='news_pi1', list_type='' where list_type='news_pi1';
```

This works for me.

Please Backup your Database before :)

Typo3 11.5.25 and news 11.0.0

Best regards Oli

Answer (score 0):

If you are using News ^11, then you can find a new upgrade wizard that takes care of your problem. News 11 has added TYPO3 12 support which makes the Plugins that use SCA obsolete. Georg wrote an upgrade wizard which automatically removes the SCA and replaces them with plugins

https://docs.typo3.org/p/georgringer/news/11.0/en-us/Misc/Changelog/11-0-0.html#split-plugins-into-separate-plugins